# Image Collection isn't able to be manipulated after mapping function

Tags: google-earth-engine

This code works well until the last two blocks. The second to last block multiplies all raster pixel values in an image collection by 10. The last block is supposed to parse the entire collection into separate collections by year. What currently happens is that the image collection seems to work for everything but the last block. When I try to put SAR100 into the parsing block, it returns zero rasters band for each year when there should definitely be more. I receive no error messages when running the code. I will include a GEE link for this code. The study area, named "geometry", is an arbitrary small polygon.

```
//Changeable Parameters
var startYear = '2016';
var startDate = '-04-01';
var endYear = '2018';
var endDate = '-09-30';
var polarization = 'VH';
var studyRegion = geometry; 

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//          Modify Sentinel-1 collection to desired specifications  
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

//Select image collection, filter it to desired polarization,
  //instrument mode, overall start/end dates, and orbital direction
var imgVV = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
        .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', polarization))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
        .select(polarization)
        .filterBounds(studyRegion)
        .filterDate( '2017-01-01', '2020-12-31')
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'));
        

//Clip image collection to study area polygon        
var clippedSAR = imgVV.map(function(image) { return image.clip(studyRegion); });
print(clippedSAR, 'clippedSAR');

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//          Multiply collection by 10
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

var SAR100 = clippedSAR.map(function(image) { 
  return image.multiply(10); 
});
print(SAR100, 'SAR100');

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//          Parse complete collection into separate years  
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

var collections = {};
for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) 
  collections[year] = SAR100.filterDate(year.toString() 
  + startDate, year.toString() + endDate).filterBounds(studyRegion);
print ('collections', collections);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7f906f531ca5ab8aad20ff2dc3cf41c8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.multiply()` does not preserve image properties.

`image.multiply(10)` is equivalent to multiplying `image` by `ee.Image.constant(10)`. `ee.Image.constant(10)` has no properties and hence you lose all properties (including `system:time_start` and `system:time_end` which are required for your date filter to work).

So while multiplying, just copy back the new properties like this

```
image.multiply(10).copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
```

[Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e238b1696ff65ec47ef15df61daba465) to fixed code.